# Operators in Heisenberg picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, conventions, density-operator, time-evolution

An operator $\hat{Q}(t)$ can be  written as $\hat{Q}(t)= e^{iHt} \hat{Q(0)} e^{-iHt}$ in Heisenberg picture.  Let us choose $\hat{Q(0)} = |{m(0)}\rangle \langle{m(0)}|$. Then $e^{iHt} \hat{Q(0)} e^{-iHt} = |{m(-t)}\rangle \langle{m(-t)}| = \hat{Q}(-t) $  and not $\hat{Q}(t)$. While as the reversing the order of evolution operators gives  $e^{-iHt} \hat{Q(0)} e^{iHt} = |{m(t)}\rangle \langle{m(t)}| = \hat{Q}(t) $. It seems that the conventional definition gets reversed here!  Interestingly, the complex conjugate of the operator $\hat{Q}(t)$ i,e. $\hat{Q}^*(t)$ follows the correct "Heisenberg prescription" of time translation.  Can someone help me to understand what is going on?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174524/50583

Comment: There is no need to interpret $|m\rangle$ as a state here, so no problem arises.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this question already  on this site  in slightly different form. But there, the difference between an operator and a state is not made clear.

Comment: Look at the time development of an expectation value, the trace of this with another operator.